# Getting correct character on keyboard event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I am making a little word game where I need to get the last char that users enters on their keyboards. I figured two ways to do this.

First one is to get each char by listening on document keyboard event and getting it by keycode. It worked very well until I started writing chars with keyboard dead keys (like Ā). String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) translates it to A as the keyCode is for the A, but there seems to be nothing on the event regarding dead key or real char that the event produced.

Second one is to keep a hidden input always focused (bad) and on keyboard event getting last char of input's value, but this only works if I write quite slowly. My code looks like this:

```
function is_char(e){
  return (!e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey &&
                        (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) || 
                        (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 122)
                );
}
$('#fake_input').on('keyup', function(e){
  if (is_char(e)){
    $('#result').append(this.value[this.value.length - 1]);
  }
}).focus();
```

Here is working example - http://jsfiddle.net/YkaBm/1/ - you should get the same word below the input, but when you write a little faster it turns out wrong.

Do you have some suggestions how to get the real (correct) character on keyboard event or why input keyup event is acting like this?

**Update!**

As I mentioned in comments semir.babajic answer didn't quite work for my case, but thanks to Semir I found that this silly solution works:

```
function is_char(e){
  return (!e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey &&
                        (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) || 
                        (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 122)
                );
}
var x = 0;
$('#fake_input').on('keyup', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 8){
    x--;
  }
  else if (is_char(e)){
    x++;
    $('#result').append(this.value[x-1]);
  }
}).focus();
```

I would still love to find a way to get the real character from keyboard event using any of $(document) keyboard events, because keeping input focused doesn't seem as a good solution.

**Update 2!**

Just in case anyone else is having similar issue, I found this solution the best:

```
App.insert_char = function(c){
    if (c && c.toUpperCase() != c.toLowerCase()){
        console.log(c);
    }
};

if ('oninput' in $('#fake_input')[0]){
    $('#fake_input').on('input', function(e){
        App.insert_char(this.value[this.value.length - 1]);
    });
}
else if ('onpropertychange' in $('#fake_input')[0]){
    $('#fake_input').on('propertychange', function(e){
        App.insert_char(this.value[this.value.length - 1]);
    });
}
else  if ('ontextInput' in $('#fake_input')[0]){
    $('#fake_input').on('textInput', function(e){
        App.insert_char(this.value[this.value.length - 1]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This line was causing a "bottleneck": `this.value[this.value.length - 1]`, it was simply slow.

Try this instead:

Updated:

```
$('#fake_input').keypress(function(e){
    $('#result').append(String.fromCharCode(e.which) + '<br />');
}).focus();
```

Explanation. I assume you'd want to use `keypress` instead of `keyup` to trap characters. Note that keyup does not have nothing to do with characters. It only tells you the keycode of the keyboard signal it received. With `keypress`, you can determine the case because you get a keycode for character.

http://jsfiddle.net/YkaBm/8/

Regards.

Comment: That won't work, because what if the character is entered by Alt + 0192

Comment: I stand corrected. :) I'd better delete the answer I was working on!

Comment: I also tried that and it works with alt key, but I have latvian keyboard and they usually have have either ` or ' as dead key, which still doesn't work with keypress and String.fromCharCode.