# Getting Charcode for open curly bracket

Tags: javascript

I need to get the char code value for the opening curly bracket.

I used `"{".charCodeAt(0)` but it returns 123,

However when If I get the value from keyboard events, that value is 219. Which one is correct?
Please advise me how to get the correct value for the curly bracket

Comment: "[charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) method returns the numeric Unicode value of the character ..." The value you can retrieve in a keyboard event depends on the event. From `keydown/up` you'd get a keyboard key mapping code, from `keypress` you'd get a numeric Unicode value of the character produced by pressed key. Please elaborate your question, i.e. define "char code".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a full list of JavaScript keyCodes available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603195/is-there-a-full-list-of-javascript-keycodes-available)

Comment: @raky, `123` is correct, test it by `String.fromCharCode(123)` gives `{`

Answer (score 1):

Yes the unicode value of { is 123 (0x7B) according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket).

However the keyCode attribute in Keyboard.event is *not* a unicode value, see [KeyboardEvent documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). People fall into the trap of using it as a character value because without the shift modifier a lot of the values are actually the same.

### KeyboardEvent.keyCode

> A system and implementation dependent numerical code identifying the
>   unmodified value of the pressed key. Read only. See the document of
>   KeyboardEvent.keyCode for the detail.

You need to get hold of the actual character. There are lots of questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253977/getting-correct-character-on-keyboard-event) on the subject.

One approach is to use `String.fromCharCode(e.which)` which will work correctly for most browsers but only for KeyboardEvents originating from keypress, not keydown, or keyup handlers.

Differences between keydown and keypress

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {console.log(e.keyCode)}, false);

 219
```

Whereas

```
document.body.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {console.log(e.keyCode)}, false);

123
```